# 'OptionalDouble.getAsDouble()' without 'isPresent()' check

Tags: java, java-stream, double, option-type

I've seen a bunch of solutions for this question but no matter what I try, IDEA still reports an error.

Consider the following block:

```
double testDouble= customClass.stream()
              .mapToDouble(CustomClass::getDouble)
              .max()
              .getAsDouble();
```

This reports a warning of `'OptionalDouble.getAsDouble()' without 'isPresent()' check`.

If I try this then it doesn't compile:

```
double testDouble= customClass.stream()
              .mapToDouble(CustomClass::getDouble)
              .max().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new)
              .getAsDouble();
```

Neither does this:

```
double testDouble= customClass.stream()
              .mapToDouble(CustomClass::getDouble)
              .max().orElse(null)
              .getAsDouble();
```

Or this:

```
double testDouble= customClass.stream()
              .mapToDouble(CustomClass::getDouble)
              .max().isPresent()
              .getAsDouble();
```

While i know these optional doubles will never be null, i'd like to resolve them so there are no warnings.

Can anyone point out where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> double testDouble= customClass.stream()
>               .mapToDouble(CustomClass::getDouble)
>               .max().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new)
>               .getAsDouble();
> ```

[`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) returns a `double`, not an `OptionalDouble`. There's no need to call `getAsDouble()`.

```
double testDouble = customClass.stream()
    .mapToDouble(CustomClass::getDouble)
    .max().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```java
final double testDouble = doubles.stream()
                .mapToDouble(CustomClass::getDouble)
                .max()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

`OptionalDouble.getAsDouble()` may throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the value is missing. `DoubleStream.max()` aggregator will return empty `OptionalDouble` when the stream is empty (when streaming empty collection, for example), but it's too difficult or even sometimes impossible for code analyzer to determine if the stream is empty, so IDEA will always warn you against this.

So even if you "*know these optional doubles will never be null*", IDEA doesn't know this. Calm her down by throwing the `IllegalArgumentException`. This will cover that possible branch of code where the optional maximum is missing.